# Unable to open image file in ui-dialog - Issue in IE 11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-dialog

I am able to work with .pdf file in both the IE and Chrome browser. But in IE following error appears for the image type file.

[image]

Below is my function for the dialog.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
        function Downloadfile(x) {
            var jquery = $;
            var empCode = $("#EmpCode").val();           
            var fileName = $(x).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
            var actualfileName = $(x).closest("tr").find('td:eq(1)').text();

            jquery("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: actualfileName,
                width: 950,
                height: 550,
                open: function () {
                    jquery('.ui-dialog').css('z-index', 2000); jquery('.ui-widget-overlay').css('z-index', 1500);
                    jquery('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css({ "background": "white", "border": "none", "text-align": "left", "font-size": "normal" });
                    jquery('span').css({ "text-align": "left", "font-size": "normal" });
                    var object = "<object data=\"http://mysitename.com/filepath/{FileName}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"900px\" height=\"500px\">";
                    object += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"http://mysitename.com/filepath/{FileName}\">here</a>";
                    object += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
                    object += "</object>";
                    object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "/" + fileName);
                    jquery("#dialog").html(object);
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: From the error message, it shows that you're trying to open a .tmp file. A [.tmp file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_file) is not an image type file and it is absolutely impossible to open by Adobe Acrobat Reader. Are you also trying to open the same .tmp file in Chrome? Please check if you're opening the right file.

Comment: @YuZhou That is not the .tmp file rather of any image file type like .jpg, .png, etc. it shows it is a .tmp file. While it works on Chrome as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by checking file type with the extension of file to be loaded in the dialog and added an extra condition if the file is of type image as shown below.

I added `img` tag for image and `src` for the path of image file to be loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Downloadfile(x) {
        var jquery = $;
        var empCode = $("#EmpCode").val();
        var fileName = $(x).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
        var actualfileName = $(x).closest("tr").find('td:eq(1)').text();

        var validExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png"];
        var file = fileName.split('.').pop();
        jquery("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: actualfileName,
            width: 950,
            height: 550,
            open: function () {
                jquery('.ui-dialog').css('z-index', 2000); jquery('.ui-widget-overlay').css('z-index', 1500);
                jquery('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css({ "background": "white", "border": "none", "text-align": "left", "font-size": "normal" });
                jquery('span').css({ "text-align": "left", "font-size": "normal" });
                var object = "<object data=\"http://mysitename.com/filepath/{FileName}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"900px\" height=\"500px\">";
                object += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"http://mysitename.com/filepath/{FileName}\">here</a>";
                object += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
                object += "</object>";
                object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "/" + fileName);
                
                //For image files
                var image = "<img src=\"http://mysitename.com/filepath/{FileName}\" width=\"900px\" height=\"500px\">"; 
                image = image.replace(/{FileName}/g, "/" + fileName);

                if (validExtensions.indexOf(file) != -1) {
                    jquery("#dialog").html(image);
                } else {
                    jquery("#dialog").html(object);
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```